# Autocorrelation of concatenated independent AR(1) processes

Tags: r, autocorrelation, independence, lags

Let $\left\{X_t\right\}$ be a stochastic process formed by concatenating iid draws from an AR(1) process, where each draw is a vector of length 10. In other words, $\left\{X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_{10}\right\}$ are realizations of an AR(1) process; $\left\{X_{11}, X_{12}, \ldots, X_{20}\right\}$ are drawn from the same process, but are independent from the first 10 observations; et cetera.

What will the ACF of $X$ -- call it $\rho\left(l\right)$ -- look like?  I was expecting $\rho\left(l\right)$ to be zero for lags of length $l \geq 10$ since, by assumption, each block of 10 observations is independent from all other blocks.

However, when I simulate data, I get this:

```
simulate_ar1 <- function(n, burn_in=NA) {
    return(as.vector(arima.sim(list(ar=0.9), n, n.start=burn_in)))
}

simulate_sequence_of_independent_ar1 <- function(k, n, burn_in=NA) {
    return(c(replicate(k, simulate_ar1(n, burn_in), simplify=FALSE), recursive=TRUE))
}

set.seed(987)
x <- simulate_sequence_of_independent_ar1(1000, 10)
png("concatenated_ar1.png")
acf(x, lag.max=100)  # Significant autocorrelations beyond lag 10 -- why?
dev.off()
```

[image: sample autocorrelation function for x]

Why are there autocorrelations so far from zero after lag 10?

My initial guess was that the burn-in in arima.sim was too short, but I get a similar pattern when I explicitly set e.g. burn_in=500.

What am I missing?

---

**Edit**: Maybe the focus on concatenating AR(1)s is a distraction -- an even simpler example is this:

```
set.seed(9123)
n_obs <- 10000
x <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.9), n_obs, n.start=500)
png("ar1.png")
acf(x, lag.max=100)
dev.off()
```

[image: acf of plain vanilla ar1]

I'm surprised by the big blocks of significantly nonzero autocorrelations at such long lags (where the true ACF $\rho(l) = 0.9^l$ is essentially zero).  Should I be?

---

**Another Edit**: maybe all that's going on here is that $\hat{\rho}$, the estimated ACF, is itself extremely autocorrelated.  For example, here's the joint distribution of $\left(\hat{\rho}(60), \hat{\rho}(61)\right)$, whose true values are essentially zero ($0.9^{60} \approx 0$):

```
## Look at joint sampling distribution of (acf(60), acf(61)) estimated from AR(1)
get_estimated_acf <- function(lags, n_obs=10000) {
    stopifnot(all(lags >= 1) && all(lags <= 100))
    x <- arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.9), n_obs, n.start=500)
    return(acf(x, lag.max=100, plot=FALSE)$acf[lags + 1])
}
lags <- c(60, 61)
acf_replications <- t(replicate(1000, get_estimated_acf(lags)))
colnames(acf_replications) <- sprintf("acf_%s", lags)
colMeans(acf_replications)  # Essentially zero
plot(acf_replications)
abline(h=0, v=0, lty=2)
```

[image: sampling distribution of estimated acf]

Comment: I hope my answer will still be of use to you, more than 1.5 years later. At least it helped me improve my R skills.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Executive summary: It seems that you are mistaking noise for true autocorrelation due to a small sample size.**

You can simply confirm this by increasing the `k` parameter in your code. See these examples below (I have used your same `set.seed(987)` throughout to maintain replicability):

k=1000 (your original code)

[image: 1000 simulations]

k=2000

[image: 2000 simulations]

k=5000

[image: 5000 simulations]

k=10000

[image: 10000 simulations]

k=50000

[image: 50000 simulations]

This sequence of images tells us two things:

- The autocorrelation after the first 10 observations greatly diminishes as the number of iterations increases. Indeed, with a sufficiently large number of iterations the $\hat\rho(l)$ for any $l>10$ will converge to zero. This is the basis for my statement at the beginning - that the autocorrelation that you observed was simply noise.
- Notwithstanding the aforementioned observation that $\hat\rho(l)$ converges to zero for any $l>10$ as the number of simulation increases, $\hat\rho(l)$ for any $l \le 10$ actually remains constant at $\hat\rho(l)=\rho(l)=0.9^l$, **just as the construction of your model would suggest.**

*Note that I refer to the **observed** autocorrelation as $\hat\rho(l)$ and to the **true** autocorrelation as $\rho(l)$.*

Comment: The sample ACF is itself autocorrelated, so it isn't _white_ noise. Other than that, I agree, it's just a noise / sample size issue.

Comment: @Adrian You are correct. I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: `It also becomes less and less likely to "stray" outside a confidence band` -- are you sure that's true?

Comment: Thanks for poking holes into the weak parts of my answer. I have to admit that statement was only based on visual inspection. I did some further research and found out that the confidence band is calculated as `qnorm((1 + ci)/2)/sqrt(x$n.used)`, i.e. $cdf(1-\alpha/2)/\sqrt{n}$ (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211628)). However, I have not been able to nail down the convergence rate for the observed autocorrelation. I asked [this new question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/314422/182174) to settle the matter but have removed this point from this answer in the meantime.

Comment: @Adrian [My question regarding the convergence rate of the observed autocorrelation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/314422/182174) has been answered. It turns out that its convergence rate is the same as the one of the confidence band: $1/{\sqrt{n}}$. My original claim that the observed autocorrelation becomes less and less likely to "stray" outside the confidence band is thus incorrect. That being said, the fact that $\hat\rho(l)$ converges to zero for any $l>10$ as the number of simulations increases still resolves your question, even if I was wrong about the relative rate of convergence.