# What is the rate of convergence of the observed autocorrelation?

Tags: autocorrelation, convergence, central-limit-theorem

How fast would the observed autocorrelation in a sample converge to the true autocorrelation (say, an AR(x) process)? Are there any results like the [Central Limit Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) - which says that the sample mean of a random sample converges to the true mean at a rate of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ - or the [Berry-Esseen theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem) that would apply to the observed autocorrelation?

*This question sprung from a minor point around [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/314014/182174) (rate of convergence of the observed autocorrelation vs rate of convergence of the confidence band in an ACF - we do know the latter) and I thought it was sufficiently general to merit its own question.*

Comment: The Berry-Esseen theorem says much more than just asserting convergence at rate $1/\sqrt{n}$, this is the job of the Central Limit Theorem. So it is not clear whether you are asking for a CLT for sample auto-correlations, or for the more specific results obtained in B-E theorem.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Thanks for correcting me. I am asking about a CLT for sample autocorrelation (if there is one).

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos I have now amended the question accordingly, thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A theorem is $6.7$. in [Hall and Heyde (1980](https://books.google.gr/books/about/Martingale_limit_theory_and_its_applicat.html?id=xxbvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)) p. 188. For a stationary process, we have

$$n^{1/2}[\hat \rho(j) - \rho(j)] \to_d N(0,v)$$

for autocorrelation of $j$-distance, and in fact, all the autocorrelations converge jointly to a multivariate normal. The authors mention that "results are available also outside the context of stationarity".

Comment: Thank you! Does this imply a convergence rate of $n^{-1/2}$? Apologies if this is obvious to you.

Comment: @Candamir In the sense that $[\hat \rho(j) - \rho(j)] = O_p(n^{-1/2})$, yes.

Comment: See also https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/207264/root-n-consistent-estimator-but-root-n-doesnt-converge/207281#207281